# how to return two object values in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that java script is dynamic lang and I wonder if there is option 
to return something similar to

```
 Inte.prototype.getM = function(sMethod) {
     return  this._mMet[sMet].ret && 
     return this._mMeth[sMet].ret.default;
  };
```

Currently when I try it as-is I got error(which is not surprising :)) .

Comment: create another object which contains these two values and return it !

Comment: Return an object (or an array)

Comment: push them into array and return it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return with an array:

```
 return  [this._mMet[sMet].ret,this._mMeth[sMet].ret.default];
```

or by an object:

```
return  {'one': this._mMet[sMet].ret, 'two': this._mMeth[sMet].ret.default};
```

**EDIT**

Based on OP comment, he want some validation on those values:

```
if (typeof this._mMet[sMet].ret == 'undefined' || typeof this._mMeth[sMet].ret.default == 'undefined') { 
    return false; 
} else { 
    return  {'one': this._mMet[sMet].ret, 'two': this._mMeth[sMet].ret.default};
}
```

Comment: just last question assume that i Use the second how should I verify that the this._mMet[sMet].ret && this._mMet[sMet].ret.defult have values since when they undefiend I got error

Comment: Before the return. just do an if statement. `if (typeof this._mMet[sMet].ret == 'undefined' || typeof this._mMeth[sMet].ret.default == 'undefined') } //do something for eg return false, } else { //add them to the object and return}`

Comment: can you please update it as answer

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to use array of objects?
For example:

```
var array = [];
array.push(this._mMet[sMet].ret);
array.push(this._mMet[sMet].ret.default);
return array;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return only one thing. But it can be array:

```
Inte.prototype.getM = function(sMethod) {
     return  [this._mMet[sMet].ret, this._mMeth[sMet].ret.default];
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return an object

```
Inte.prototype.getM = function(sMethod) {
     return {
         ret: this._mMet[sMet].ret,
         retDefault: this._mMeth[sMet].ret.default
    };
};
```

Then you can access it using

```
var returnObject = inte.getM(arguements);
var ret = returnObject.ret //equvalent to returnObject['ret'];
var retDefault= returnObject.retDefault //equivalent to returnObject['retDefault'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way for this is

```
function a(){
     var first=firstObject;
     var second=secondObject;
     return {first:first,second:second};
}
```

Then use

```
a().first // first value
a().second // second value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to retun as array:

```
Inte.prototype.getM = function(sMethod) {
     return new Array(this._mMet[sMet].ret,this._mMeth[sMet].ret.default);
};
```